# How can I get tag's post with Eloquent ORM

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I have proper ORM based post and tags tables. Tags assigning to post over a pivot table. To get posts->tags in laravel I use below model relation.

```
//Model: Post
public function tags()
{
$this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Here's my database:

```
post
  id

tags
  id

post_tag
  post_id
  tag_id
```

## Question

I want to retrieve all posts that has a spesific tag name.

## What I tried

`Post::with(array('tags' => function($query)
        {
            $query->where('id', '=', 44);
        }))->get();` with eager loading. But gave integrity error.

Also I tried query relation, throw non-object error.

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function($q)
{
    $q->where('id', '=', $tag_id);

})->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship is bidirectional

you need to define your model Tag
as

```
class Tag{
    public function posts()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}
```

you could then do

```
$posts = Tag::find(44)->posts;
```